# How do I get my chests in Minecraft to face the way I want?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While making a storage room for all my mined cobblestone from my quarry, I came across a rather *cosmetic* problem with my chests: not all of them face me.
[image: my chests]

I realized that chests only face towards me when they have a block blocking it from behind, but it is rather ugly:
[image: chest with ugly dirt block behind]

So, how do I make them all face me? Is it possible to do it without placing a solid block behind it?

**EDIT:** Just FYI, they will turn back when I remove the block behind it.

Comment: I was under the impression that the "face" of the chest would point toward the player as they placed them. I will have to check this out later.

Comment: what tileset is that? It looks nice.

Comment: It's [piehole-pattern](http://piehole.alexvoelk.de/), i got sick of my old texture pack

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An option that may be more or less drastic, depending on how much work you've already done: Rearrange your storage room so all the chests face west.

> The front of the chest (with the latch) will face away from any adjacent solid blocks, or face west if placed independent of other blocks. The viewpoint of players has no effect on the orientation of placed chests. *—[Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chest)*

Since these are double chests they only have two "choices" of which way to face. If that choice doesn't include west (i.e., you've got them facing north-south), then it's probable that arranging them all to face south will have the same effect. That's assuming that the chests face west when they're alone due to the [south/west rule](https://minecraft.wiki/w/South/West_rule).

Comment: +1 for citing that 'by default they face this way'. That is just the way the work is all.

Answer (score 5):

<s>You should be able to remove that dirt block and it will be fine.</s>

You could edit the back of the chest texture so it matches the front.

The other option is to place halfsteps behind. This would not look too bad.

Comment: they will turn back, and if i edit the back of the chest texture, it will affect the correct-facing ones.

Comment: What I was referring to is copying the front to the back - you have universally front sided chests. It will not affect the correct facing ones since you'll only see one side.

Comment: @Duck This is my current solution, and some texture packs now include an option to turn this on/off